# Texture Painting - Paint Not Fully Applying (Not Brush Weight)

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

Good afternoon,

I have been working on creating some pieces of terrain in Blender 2.78 and have not had any issues with Texture Painting until today.

When I went to start painting, instead of the texture I want solidly covering the ground, it does nothing but draw my brush circle and then when I drag, it gives a dashed line from where I started to where the circle is.  If I drag far enough, it does paint, but it is always transparent and I can see the grid squares.

[image]
I am guessing it is some kind of setting that I accidentally hit a shortcut for, but it is driving me crazy and halted my progress last night.

Thank you for any assistance I can get.

EDIT:  Solved the question about the lag behind in the painting, but now I don't know why with even full weight I cannot cover the grid image...

And here are my brush settings.
[image]

Comment: Looks like you enabled Smooth Stroke option which allows to smoothen the final stroke, probably you pressed Shift+S when in Texture Paint mode

Comment: The question about it dragging behind, that is resolved, you are correct in that I turned that option on.  I was trying to use the SHIFT+F Nav mode, but I was A.) In Texture Paint Mode and B.) Fat Fingered and "S" instead of "F".

The only other issue I have now is my paint is not full taking over the grid like in the terrain adjacent, and I have the weight at 1.0 (full).

Comment: So the texture mixing is working, it is just slower than it seemed to be before when it comes to filling in a mix.  I think this can be considered resolved though.